# Como instalar librerias de python en pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pillow

Quiero descargar la libreria pillow, lo que he intentado ha sido: File>Settings>Project Interpreter> le doy al +, escribo pillow, le doy instalar y sale error, este es el output:

> Collecting Pillow   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/47/f28067b187dd664d205f75b07dcc6e0e95703e134008a14814827eebcaab/Pillow-7.0.0.tar.gz
>   Installing collected packages: Pillow   Running setup.py install for
>   Pillow: started
>       Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
>       Complete output from command "C:\Users\julia\Documents\Luis Güerere\Programacion\Proyectos\Battleship3D\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-18by9uni\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\julia\Documents\Luis
>   Güerere\Programacion\Proyectos\Battleship3D\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow":
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.8
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       copying src\PIL__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\PIL
>       running egg_info
>       writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
>       writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
>       writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
>       reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
>       warning: no files found matching '*.c'
>       warning: no files found matching '*.h'
>       warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
>       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
>       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
>       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
>       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
>       warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
>       warning: no previously-included files found matching 'azure-pipelines.yml'
>       warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
>       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
>       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
>       no previously-included directories found matching '.azure-pipelines'
>       no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
>       writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
>
> ```
> running build_ext
>
>
> The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
> a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
> Please see the install instructions at:
>    https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 852, in 
>           setup(
>         File "C:\Users\julia\Documents\Luis Güerere\Programacion\Proyectos\Battleship3D\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools__init__.py",
>   line 145, in setup
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py",
>   line 148, in setup
>           dist.run_commands()
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 966, in run_commands
>           self.run_command(cmd)
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\julia\Documents\Luis Güerere\Programacion\Proyectos\Battleship3D\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\command\install.py",
>   line 61, in run
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py",
>   line 545, in run
>           self.run_command('build')
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py",
>   line 313, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py",
>   line 135, in run
>           self.run_command(cmd_name)
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py",
>   line 313, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py",
>   line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py",
>   line 340, in run
>           self.build_extensions()
>         File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py",
>   line 687, in build_extensions
>           raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
>       **main**.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 907, in 
>           raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
>       **main**.RequiredDependencyException:
>
> ```
> The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
> a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>
> Please see the install instructions at:
>    https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>
>
>
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command ""C:\Users\julia\Documents\Luis
>   Güerere\Programacion\Proyectos\Battleship3D\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-18by9uni\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\julia\Documents\Luis
>   Güerere\Programacion\Proyectos\Battleship3D\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow""
>   failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\

Comment: En google hay varios articulos que te pueden ayudar mira [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188838/cant-install-pillow-in-windows) y [GitHub](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4242)

Answer (score 1):

piensas instalarlo en linux o windows?
[en esta guía](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.2/) y [esta otra guía](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) habla como hacerlo.
Ten esto en cuenta:

- Pillow y PIL no pueden coexistir en el mismo entorno. Antes de instalar Pillow, desinstale PIL.
  Por si tenias instalado PIL ya sabes.
- Pillow> = 1.0 ya no admite "importar imagen". En su lugar, use "from PIL import Image".
- Pillow> = 2.1.0 ya no es compatible con "import _imaging". Utilice "from PIL.Image import core como _imaging" en su lugar.

---

Puedes instalar pillow con pip desde la consola de comandos.

- pip install Pillow

si no te funciona de esta manera, intenta esta otra forma:

- python -m pip install Pillow

Y, si no tienes instalado pip, lo puedes instalar de esta forma:

- python -m pip install pip

---

si no te funciona, intenta instalarlo manualmente.

- Pillow para python 2.7, [acá](https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.5.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe#md5=33c3a581ff1538b4f79b4651084090c8)
- Pillow para python 3, [acá](https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.5.3.win-amd64-py3.4.exe#md5=6ee659d7b945e826a07c53c15578424f)
- Otras versiones, [acá](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/)

---

segun [esta guía](https://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac/), necesitas instalar también,cImage, un módulo de Python utilizado para el procesamiento de imágenes.

- [acá](https://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac/) se explica como instalarlo, te toca manualmente.

---

Espero y sea de ayuda la respuesta.